# google.colab.drive is unsupported in this environment

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am using Colab instance that is connected to Google Cloud to train a neural model using NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB.

I want to load my files from my Google Drive but I am not able.

```
try:
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

When I run the above code I get this error:

> google.colab.drive is unsupported in this environment.

What is the problem?

When I try to import my files using a Colab that is not connected to Google Cloud, it works fine.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Any solution yet ?

Comment: @NaveenGabriel  Nope. I think Google doesn't support access to `Drive` when we use the advanced GPUs. Maybe for security reasons.

Comment: @Minions that is misleading. I tried using VMs without GPU and still have the same error.

Comment: It was answered on the Github Issues Section. Refer to this thread for solution: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2533#issuecomment-1018080844